# Where is the python mechanize cache/temp folder? How can I clear it? How can I retrieve files from it?

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm on Ubuntu. I'd like to be able to retrieve images saved in my temp folder, and clear it, at will (or does mechanize not actually read images but rather just html?).

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize doesn't retrieve images unless you specifically tell it to (on a one by one basis).

Comment: Do you mean by performing open(image) or can I pass an argument to open(page_html, like download_images.name="x") or something?

Comment: You have to call `open()` on every url you want to open (including images), mechanize doesn't automatically retrieve the images included in a page.